# combine C++20 Modules and includes

Tags: c++, module

CMake has finally dropped the experimental status of CXX modules. I'm giving it a try  now :)

In our codebase we are using a (generated) config header. This config header contains some std lib includes (,  etc.). As a start I'd like to extract all std lib includes and place them into a single module so that these headers will only be compiled once.
(import std is not yet supported by cmake).
The example code was taken from [kitware blog](https://www.kitware.com/import-cmake-the-experiment-is-over/)

Now my question is: If std headers are included in a module and are also included in the source file later, will they be compiled twice (in module.cxx and main.cpp)? If so the build time would probably not decrease

//module.cxx

```
// Global module fragment where #includes can happen
module;
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// first thing after the Global module fragment must be a module command
export module foo;


export class foo {
public:
  foo();
  ~foo();
  void helloworld() const;

  void print(auto str);
};

foo::foo() = default;
foo::~foo() = default;
void foo::helloworld() const { std::cout << "hello world\n"; }

void foo::print(auto str)
{
  std::cout << "Some template test" << str << std::endl;
}




//main.cpp
import foo;


#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
  foo f;
  f.helloworld();
  std::string str = "std::string";
  constexpr char cStr[] = "cString";
  f.print(str);
  f.print(cStr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Each header will be compiled each time it is included into translation unit. If you are looking for decreasing compilation times then you should look at precompiled headers instead.